# Injection of autowired dependencies failed Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am developing a small Java EE Hibernate Spring application and the following error appears :

> SEVERE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé
>   (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener)
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'responsableServiceImpl': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.drp.dao.ResponsableDao
>   com.drp.service.impl.ResponsableServiceImpl.responsableDao; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'responsableDaoImpl': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.drp.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   Collection has neither generic type or OneToMany.targetEntity()
>   defined: com.drp.model.Drp.decisions
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: private com.drp.dao.ResponsableDao
>   com.drp.service.impl.ResponsableServiceImpl.responsableDao; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'responsableDaoImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.drp.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   Collection has neither generic type or OneToMany.targetEntity()
>   defined: com.drp.model.Drp.decisions

**ListResponsableBean.java :**

```
package com.drp.beans;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.drp.model.Responsable;
import com.drp.service.ResponsableService;

@Component
@ManagedBean(name="listResponsableBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ListResponsableBean  implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6675856254221490117L;

@Autowired
private ResponsableService respService;

private List<Responsable> reponsables;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    reponsables = respService.getResponsable();
}

public ResponsableService getRespService() {
    return respService;
}   

public void setRespService(ResponsableService respService) {
    this.respService = respService;
}

public List<Responsable> getReponsables() {
    return reponsables;
}

public void setReponsables(List<Responsable> reponsables) {
    this.reponsables = reponsables;
}
```

}

**ResponsableDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.drp.dao.impl;
import com.drp.dao.ResponsableDao;
import com.drp.model.Responsable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class ResponsableDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Responsable, Integer> implements ResponsableDao {

public ResponsableDaoImpl() {
    super(Responsable.class);
}

public ResponsableDaoImpl(Class<Responsable> type) {
    super(type);
}

}
```

**GenericDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.drp.dao.impl;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.drp.dao.GenericDao;

public class GenericDaoImpl<T , I extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, I>{

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Class<T> type;

public GenericDaoImpl(Class<T> type){
    this.type = type;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}    
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public T find(I id) {
    return (T) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().get(type, id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<T> findAll(){

return (List<T>) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from "+type.getName()).list();        

}
@Transactional
@Override
public void delete(T obj) {
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(obj);

}
   @Transactional
@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(T obj) {
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(obj);
}    

}
```

**ResponsableServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.drp.service.impl;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.drp.dao.ResponsableDao;
import com.drp.model.Responsable;
import com.drp.service.ResponsableService;

@Service
public class ResponsableServiceImpl implements ResponsableService {

@Autowired
private ResponsableDao responsableDao;  

@Override
public List<Responsable> getResponsable() {
    return responsableDao.findAll();

}

public ResponsableDao getResponsableDao() {
    return responsableDao;
}

public void setResponsableDao(ResponsableDao responsableDao) {
    this.responsableDao = responsableDao;
}
```

}

**ResponsableService.java**

```
package com.drp.service;
import java.util.List;
import com.drp.model.Responsable;

public interface ResponsableService {
public List <Responsable> getResponsable();

}
```

Comment: Explain your error with minimal code possible

Comment: The problem is that your hibernate `SessionFactory` isn't getting created. You may find error in it's configuration.

Comment: AnnotationException: Collection has neither generic type or OneToMany.targetEntity() defined: com.drp.model.Drp.decisions. check out your Drp entity and decisions field

Comment: Where you are defining the `@ComponentScan`?

Comment: I am using <context:component-scan base-package="com.drp.*"> to define the componenet scan in applicationContext.xml

Comment: I have solved my problem it was caused by a wrong declaration of the decision attribut in the drp model class it was declared as follow private Set decisions = new HashSet (0); and i modified it as follow private Set<Decision>decisions = new HashSet<Decision>(0);